# Recursive and non recursive functions

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following code that prints true if a given number is even and false if its odd.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long x = 2222224;
    if (x % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else{
        System.out.println("False");}
      }
```

My trouble is I am a bit new to java, and I am having trouble differentiating recursive from non-recursive functions. Is the above code recursive, if yes, how can I write a non recursive one.

Comment: Above code is non-recursive and dont found any use to make such logic recursive at all

Comment: The above code is not recursive at all.

Comment: A function is recursive if it calls itself..for one to understand recursion, one must understand recursion.

Comment: @Youngistan `You can't make any code recursive while writing in main method` ? `static void main(String[] a) { main(a); }` ?

Comment: wikipedia knows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: @Youngistan - `main` most certainly can be recursive!!

Comment: A recursive method is one that calls itself.  It's that simple.  Ideally, it will not *inevitably* call itself along all possible paths, and hence the recursion will end before the thread runs out of stack, but that's not a requirement for the method to be "recursive".

Comment: What if have the code in a method called EvenOdd, and call it from the main method? It's still non recursive right?

Comment: Does the method call itself or not?  (Though note that we must count even indirect paths for "call itself".  A calls B calls C calls A is recursive.)

Comment: @Hustl3r28 Your code is recursive if and when it enters a cyclical pattern. If you have a recursive method, you'll have to call it from somewhere outside of that method to start with. Calling the method `isRecursive()` from the `main()` method doesn't change the fact that `isRecursive()` is a recursive method.

Comment: you just confused me even more.

Comment: someone is pretty generous with the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Method is not recursive

recursive method calls itself e.g:

```
void myMethod( int counter) {
    if(counter == 0)
        return;
    else {
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);
        myMethod(--counter);
        System.out.println(""+counter);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forger the ending curly bracket } for the function

Comment: What if have the code in a method called EvenOdd, and call it from the main method? It's still non recursive right?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive method calls itself with an adjusted set of parameters - and as your method is `main` and does not call `main` it is *not* recursive.

Comment: What if have the code in a method called EvenOdd, and call it from the main method? It's still non recursive right?

Comment: @Hustl3r28 - It doesn't matter what the method is named.

Comment: @Hustl3r28: Yes. To clarify slightly, however, a function, to be recursive, does not necessarily have to call *itself*; it could also be a matter of two or more functions that call each other in a repeated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the method your code is in, and so what you have is not recursive. Your program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long x = 2222224;
    if (x % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else{
        System.out.println("False");}
      }
```

prints out `True` and nothing else. If you wanted to print out every value from 2222224 - 0 you could use recursion (though a loop would be more efficient).

A method that calls itself is recursive:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    recursiveMethod(2222224);
}

public static void recursiveMethod(int x){
    if(x > 0){
        if (x % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("False");
        }
        recursiveMethod(x - 1);
    }
}
```

The above version prints `True` or `False` 2222224 times. Once for each value from 2222224 - 0.

Comment: @user56029283888 worth the comment, but not a minus -.- easy fix

Comment: I didnt thumb you down, someone else did